# HighCharts Parameters meaning - plotX,plotLeft,shapeArgs

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

Can someone please tell from where to know about the different Series object meanings like plotX,plotLeft and all..in highcharts???

I searched the documentation but not able to find.

I am trying to understand this piece of code.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },


    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart,
                            r = chart.renderer,
                            shape = this.shapeArgs,
                            xAxis = this.series.xAxis,
                            yAxis = this.series.yAxis,
                            y = yAxis.toPixels(this.total),
                            x = this.plotX + chart.plotLeft - shape.width / 2,
                            height = yAxis.toPixels(yAxis.min) - y;

                        if (chart.hoverStack) {
                            chart.hoverStack.destroy()
                        }

                        chart.hoverStack = r.rect(x, y, shape.width, height).attr({
                            'stroke-width': 6,
                                'stroke': 'black',
                            fill: 'transparent',
                        }).add();

                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        if (this.series.chart.hoverStack) {
                            this.series.chart.hoverStack.destroy();
                            this.series.chart.hoverStack = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'John',
        data: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Bob',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Ken',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/3Utat/25/

Comment: These are inner methods, you need to dig in the sources to understand what are these options. `plotX` -> x-position for plotting the point, `shapeArgs` -> object with shape arguments for rendering in SVG, `plotLeft` -> left margin/spacing between border and plotting area.

Comment: @PawełFus..Yea i will look into tht...

Answer (score 1):

For bar instead of column, use:

```
plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function(){
                        console.info(this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and see what you get for values when you hover over the bar.  Hope this helps